# Where's apjsua?

Tags: android, sip, pjsip

I'm'trying to use the pjsip lib for android, after reading some sites talking about the topic I still wondering how to use it. 
Many examples suggest to start it building the apjsua folder in the downloaded package but I cannot find it in /pjproject-2.1.0/pjsip-apps/src/

I have all the other sources put not apjsua, does this folder have another name since the new version?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PJSIP has not yet released there Android version, it is only for testing purposes.
You can find the PJSIP projest for android in branches. Here is the link : ​http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/branches/projects/android/

So I would suggest you to download the whole pjproject.

You can find the apjsua in pjproject/branches/projects/android/pjsip-apps/src/apjsua

Answer (score 1):

In some versions its name is apjsua and in other versions its pjsua.
Checkout code from below link:
​
http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk

After checkout and building it with given commands on PJSIP getting started page, you will find it in following path:

```
 PJSIP_DIR/pjsip_apps/src/pjsua/android/
```

For confirmation, you can check it by browsing code on following link:

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/browser